# Overclock when performance is needed, underclock when idle

Tags: cpu, ubuntu-12.04, overclocking, underclock

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I would like to know if I can underclock my CPU when my computer is idle, and overclock *when* performance is *needed*. Is there some sort of software I can install and use? Or is is a hardware based thing? Any suggestions? Thanks!

P.S.

Here are my CPU specs (just in case):

`Intel® Atom™ CPU N270 @ 1.60GHz × 2`

Answer (score 4):

On the hardware size [your processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/36331) supports SpeedStep (Intel CPU feature). Just make sure it is enabled in the BIOS.

> Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® Technology is an advanced means of enabling
>   high performance while meeting the power-conservation needs of mobile
>   systems. Conventional Intel SpeedStep® Technology switches both
>   voltage and frequency in tandem between high and low levels in
>   response to processor load. Enhanced Intel SpeedStep® Technology
>   builds upon that architecture using design strategies such as
>   Separation between Voltage and Frequency Changes, and Clock
>   Partitioning and Recovery.

On the OS side yours will utilize SpeedStep by default if it is enabled. To take a look at what it is doing install cpufreqtools by running `sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils` and then run `cpufreq-info`.

Comment: This seems to be a common feature on laptops now. My Lenovo X220 for example adjusts the CPU speed based on the power source. It also has a "boost" feature that 'overclocks' the CPU (but not outside its thermal design limits) in some circumstances.

Comment: How can I tell if SpeedStep is enabled and how can I enable it if not?

Comment: I see this:
`The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use within this range.` Does that mean SpeedStep is enabled?

Comment: Yes. Should also be showing the low/high freq and how many steps in between along with how much time the processor has spent at each frequency. Can add a "as suggest ran cpufreq-info and this was the result" to your question.